# Understanding FFT output from Jtransform and ColumbiaFFT

Tags: java, fft

I obtain a result that I don't understand when I apply the FFT of Jtransform.

The output frequency I get, is different from what I expect.

Currently I try to use Jtransform. From this library, I used [`realForward(double[] a)`](http://wendykierp.github.io/JTransforms/apidocs/org/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.html#realForward-double:A-).

To test the application, I used the following parameters:

- *input frequency = 50 hz*
- *sample rate = 1 Khz*
- *signal length = 1024*

Below is a code snippet of the test method I wrote:

```
private static void test() {
    //double[] signal = {980, 988, 1160, 1080, 928, 1068, 1156, 1152, 1176, 1264};

    int signalLength = 1024;
    double[] signal = new double[signalLength];
    double sampleRate = 1000;
    // Generate sin signal f = 50 , SampleRate = 0,001
    for (int i = 0; i < signal.length; i++) {
        signal[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * 50.0 / sampleRate);
    }
    // Copy signal for columbiaFFT
    double signal2[] = signal.clone();
    // Calculate FFT using Jtransforms
    DoubleFFT_1D fft_1D = new DoubleFFT_1D(signal.length);
    fft_1D.realForward(signal);

    double[] magResult = new double[signal.length / 2];

    double re, im;
    magResult[0] = signal[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < magResult.length - 1; i++) {
        re = signal[i * 2];
        im = signal[i * 2 + 1];
        magResult[i] = Math.sqrt(re * re + im * im);
    }
    // converting bin to frequency values
    double[] bin2freq = new double[magResult.length];

    // sampleRate is in Hz
    for (int i = 0; i < bin2freq.length; i++) {
        bin2freq[i] = i * sampleRate / magResult.length;
        //bin2freq[i] = i  * sampleRate / * signal.length;
    }
    System.out.println("freq 1 " + bin2freq[1]);


    // Calculate FFT using columbiaFFT
    FFTColumbia fftColumbia = new FFTColumbia(signalLength);
    double[] imaginary = new double[signal2.length];
    fftColumbia.fft(signal2, imaginary);
    double[] magColumbia = new double[signal2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < magColumbia.length; i++) {
        magColumbia[i] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(signal2[i], 2) + Math.pow(imaginary[i], 2));
    }

}
```

When I plot the magnitude of the signal apart from seeing a noise and having negative result for the amplitude which I think it could come from not applying a window, I obtain an unexpected f-plot from applying fft of Jtransform ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDUtr.png)).

I also would like to ask if the [FFT Columbia algorithm](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html) is displaying directly the frequency and amplitude or if it is also displaying the bin and I would therefore have to convert it to F.

[See Plotting FFT Columbia vs Jtransform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI1DB.png)

Blue signal is FFT Columbia output 
Red signal is FFT Jtransform output

If that's the case I might have generated the signal wrong.

Comment: The plot refer to magResult or magColumbia ?

Comment: The problem with the Jtransform plot is the frequency peak, its is at 200 hz and I think it should be at 50 Hz.

Comment: Ok, so the red is Jtransform.

Comment: Can't edit previous comment Sorry! The problem with the Jtransform plot is the frequency peak, its is at 200 Hz and I think it should be at 50 Hz. In the second plot fftColumbia vs Jtransform fftColumbia f peak is at bin 50 -> 50Bin * 1000Hz/1024 Samples = 48 Hz  and Jtransform is at bin 100 -> 100Bin * 1000Hz / 512 Samples = 195 Hz

Comment: I'm trying to find out why it's not working and comparing it with complexForward or realForwardFull. Can you try it with complexForward, as i might be a layout mapping issue ( why mag[0] = signal[0], and they also say mag[1] = Re[n/2])
By the way shouldn't the loop ending condition be" i<magResult.length" instead of "magResult.length - 1" ?

Comment: realForwardfull and complexForward give me the same bin and in my opinion the right bin 50 -> 50 * 1000 Hz /1024 = 48Hz. You are right the ending condition of the loop should be ´i<magResult.length´ and mag[0] = signal[0] its because the first output of the FFT doesn't have imaginary part only real and should be 0 because is the mean value of the full signal in this case it isn't 0 because I didn't apply any filter and the  sin signal was cropped in the midle of a peak.

Comment: You dont show equivalent code; show how you display the graphs then we will see

Comment: To display the graphs I use matplotlib from python. For the X axis I fill it with numbers from `0 to magResult.length` and Y values are the output  of the fft, from what I have understood of FFT, but I am not completly sure, is that each FFT magnitude in this case: `magResult[i]` corresponds to one bin and you can convert each bin to a Frequency in this case `bin2freq[i] = i * sampleRate / magResult.length;`  When I use realForwardFull and complexForward I have a magnitude peak @bin = 50  -> bin50 * 1000 / 1024 = 48 Hz Which It's the expected result