# How do convert an audio clip into an array to perform an FFT?

Tags: java, audio, fft

I want to write a program that will read sound files of different instruments playing the same note, and show the different signature frequencies.

The library I am using to do so is JTransforms, since it seemed to be the one that was recommended the most to perform FFTs in java. I have not found any clear explanations on how to use this library, but from what I can gather, I need to pass in an array of real and complex numbers into the methods provided by the library. How do I get these numbers from my audio clips? 
I have very basic knowledge of sound processing, since this is only my term project for my first computer science class.

Comment: typically your audio data is a floating point array which you send into a fft call which will return a new array of complex numbers ... the real skill is in ability to make sense of the array returned from the fft call ... see details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55699449/147175

Comment: help your self - with a classmate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782983/understanding-fft-output-from-jtransform-and-columbiafft

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17429407/1501661) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17565269/1501661) question you need to read file as array of bytes. Don't worry about complex numbers, because you need only real part and can fill imaginary part with 0 (you can see it also in questions I linked above).